# Using SQL how do I select the value of a translated field in a specific language?

Tags: i18n-l10n, database

Give an entity field that has been translated into the target language, how do I retrieve a specific language version using SQL - not php.

Give this query for instance (using an imaginary field called data on an entity form):

```
SELECT field_method_value 
FROM entityform
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_method
ON entityform.entityform_id = field_data_field_method.entity_id
```

And assuming that we have a default language of English (en) and Spanish (es) enabled on our site, and that a translated value for the spanish version of the field is stored...

What SQL statement would return the Spanish version rather than the English one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field language is stored in the `language` column of each row in the field table.

So you just need to add a simple condition to your SQL, e.g.

```
language = 'es'
```

Comment: Got it - how lovely to find it so simple, even if embarassing to have missed it! - Many thanks Clive.